# JSON "Any" is not covertible to 'NSDictionary' and how to decide the casting type

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I have been working on core data in this project.
I need to retrieve data from a json file then get certain data into core data.  However, i get stuck on type casting.

```
[![do {
  let][1]][1] jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

    let jsonArray = jsonDict.value(forKeyPath: "response.venues") as! NSArray

    for jsonDictionary: NSDictionary in jsonArray {

    let venueName = jsonDictionary["name"] as? String
    let venuePhone = (jsonDictionary as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "contact.phone") as? String
    let specialCount = (jsonDictionary as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "specials.count") as? NSNumber

    let locationDict = jsonDictionary["location"] as! NSDictionary
    let priceDict = jsonDictionary["price"] as! NSDictionary
    let statsDict = jsonDictionary["stats"] as! NSDictionary

    let location = Location(entity: locationEntity!, insertInto: coreDataStack.context)
    location.address = locationDict["address"] as? String
    location.city = locationDict["city"] as? String
    location.state = locationDict["state"] as? String
    location.zipcode = locationDict["postalCode"] as? String
    location.distance = locationDict["distance"] as? NSNumber

    let category = Category(entity: categoryEntity!, insertInto: coreDataStack.context)

    let priceInfo = PriceInfo(entity: priceEntity!, insertInto: coreDataStack.context)
    priceInfo.priceCategory = priceDict["currency"] as? String

    let stats = Stats(entity: statsEntity!, insertInto: coreDataStack.context)
    stats.checkinsCount = statsDict["checkinsCount"] as? NSNumber
    stats.usersCount = statsDict["userCount"] as? NSNumber
    stats.tipCount = statsDict["tipCount"] as? NSNumber

    let venue = Venue(entity: venueEntity!, insertInto: coreDataStack.context)
    venue.name = venueName
    venue.phone = venuePhone
    venue.specialCount = specialCount
    venue.location = location
    venue.category = category
    venue.priceInfo = priceInfo
    venue.stats = stats
  }
```

[image]

And my JSON tree is here as well:[image]

I have been try a few subscript, which does not work at all. How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try to use `[Any]` instead of `NSArray` and `[String:Any]` instead of `NSDictionary`

2) You will probably need to extract `venues` from `response`

Like this in **Swift 3**:

```
do {
      let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
      let jsonResponseArray = jsonDict["response"] as! [Any]
      let jsonVenueArray = jsonResponseArray["venues"] as! [String:Any]
      for venue: [String:Any] in jsonVenueArray {
             ...
      }
} catch {
    print("Error:", error)
}
```

Comment: Swift 3 Dictionary native value type should be `Any` not `AnyObject`. BTW Dictionary has no `value(forKeyPath:)` method

Comment: @LeoDabus Any and AnyObject is a bit confusing to be. Using AnyObject in this case will not work ?

Comment: String, Float, Double are structures and AnyObject is a protocol which all classes implicitly conforms to (not strucs). If you use AnyObject all Double, Float, Int will be converted to NSNumber

Comment: @LeoDabus Get it! I changed the answer.

Comment: don't forget to handle the error using `do try catch` error handling or use `try?` to return an optional and not handle the error `if let dict =  (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)) as? [String:Any] {`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus !

Comment: you are welcome. BTW no need to cast to NSError. just `print(error)` and `options: allowFragments` is not needed

Comment: I did follow your advice and The complier says ," Cannot subscript a value of type '[Any]' with an index of type 'String' " on the line : let jsonVenueArray = jsonResponseArray["venues"] as! [String:Any]

Comment: It looks like a parser problem. Copy and Paste your json file at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu to get a better structure view of the file.

Comment: I did and i eventually figure out the issue, which is i did not cast the item in the array after i loop them. And thanks a lot for your help :)